# Add bindings to Function.Json When Deploying Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I've come across a lot online saying it's bad practice to edit the Function.Json as a post-build process. The recommendations are setting the App.Settings on the Azure Function but what I want to do it replace the bindings in the Function.Json how do I do that in the app settings? I essentially want the same values in my local.settings.json to override the Function.Json

**My local.settings.json**

```
    {
....
  "bindings": [
        {
          "type": "queueTrigger",
          "direction": "in",
          "name": "myQueueItem",
          "queueName": "dev-inbound",
          "connection": "connectionStringV1"
        }
      ]
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so in the app settings I added a new key called "bindings" and simply added fields in as a JSON object. This will override the bindings in the Function.Json file

Comment: this does not work

Comment: Strange, it worked for me at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to do it is to use %VARIABLE_NAME% in function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "%QUEUE_NAME%",
      "connection": "SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use values from the `appsettings.json` file for your binding configuration, you can use the `${}` syntax. For example, if you want to specify the connection string for a storage account, you could set the value in `appsettings.json` like this:

```
{
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=mykey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

And in your function.json file, you could use the `${}` syntax to reference the connection string like this:

```
{
  "name": "inputBlob",
  "type": "blob",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "mycontainer/{name}",
  "connection": "${AzureWebJobsStorage}"
}
```

This will ensure that the connection string for the storage account is read from the appsettings.json file and used as the connection string for the inputBlob binding.

Note that the `${}` syntax can be used to reference any key-value pair in the appsettings.json file, not just connection strings.